# how to deactive enter event (only enter no shift+enter) in contenteditable

Tags: jquery, html

I want to use `contenteditable` attribute in my code but I have one problem.

I want when click (**shift + enter**) go on next line (**point: I want only shift + enter go to next line**) and When I click enter key hidden text in this div that has `contenteditable`  attribute.

please guide me about it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you possibly set up a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with your code demonstrating the issue, please?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the keydown event for this. [Mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/keydown) has more information about this event.

With the following example html:

```
<div id="pinky" contenteditable="true">Pink unicorns are blue</div>
```

You can attach an keydown event handler to this element. We can then use the `event.shiftKey` to detect if the shiftKey is pressed together with our enter key. Key 13 is either of the "enter" keys.

```
$('#pinky').on('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.which === 13 && e.shiftKey === false) {
    //Prevent insertion of a return
    //You could do other things here, for example
    //focus on the next field
    return false;
  }
});
```

---

This snippets shows this in action:

```js
$('#pinky').on('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.which === 13 && e.shiftKey === false) {
    //Prevent insertion of a return
    //You could do other things here, for example
    //focus on the next field
    return false;
  }
});
```

```css
#pinky {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pinky" contenteditable="true">Pink unicorns are blue</div>
```